# Macbook Air very slow Wi-Fi after High Sierra upgrade

Tags: mac, network, wifi, high-sierra

I have a Macbook Air that has insanely slow Wi-Fi after High Sierra upgrade.  A clean install of El Capitan and resetting the PRAM has the Wi-Fi working as normal.  I get between 200-300mbps down.  As soon as I install High Sierra, the Wi-Fi cannot get speeds over 1-2 mbps.  I have no apps or files on this machine other than the clean install.  (Because Apple won't allow me to save the High Sierra download file, I have to first install El Capitan or other os version before upgrading to High Sierra.)

I have tried the following:

- Resetting SMC
- Resetting PRAM
- Removing all Wi-Fi settings by removing the following files from /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/

  - com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
  - com.apple.network.identification.plist
  - com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist
  - NetworkInterfaces.plist
  - preferences.plist
- Rebooting the router
- Rebooting the Mac
- Using a manual IP
- Installing another Airport card.

Nothing works.  The machine passes the Apple Hardware test with no issues found.  Ethernet via a USB adapter works flawlessly.  I'm completely stumped.